# Как обновить страницу и выполнить JS скрипт на стороннем сайте

Tags: javascript

Имею N сайт, он не мой, как можно обновлять страницу и выполнять скрипт, который снова выполняет перезагрузку и вызывает самого себя?

Допустим имею такой код

```
console.log(12345)
```

Как выполнить с этим кодом что я написал выше?

Comment: Написать расширение для браузера

Comment: Насколько я знаю так нельзя делать на других сайтах.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать **Tampermonkey**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    sitelink
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://url-вхождение*
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        console.log(12345);
        document.location.reload(true); //перезагрузка страницы

    });
})(jQuery);
```